# How to re-index arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

**How to re-arrange:**

```
Array (
     [0] => tomato
     [2] => apple
     [3] => melon
     [4] => Cherry
     [7] => banana 
)
```

**To:**

```
Array (
     [0] => tomato
     [1] => apple
     [2] => melon
     [3] => Cherry
     [4] => banana 
)
```

?

Comment: `sort()` will re-index your array, but also reorder / sort it, which means apple = 0, banana = 1 etc.

Comment: From another answer: array_splice($array, 0, 0);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just try with [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$newArray = array_values($oldArray);
```

Comment: would `$oldArray = array_values($oldArray);` work?

Comment: Yes, it will. I have named result with `$newArray` to show how it works.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($original_array as $val) { 
 $new_array[] = $val;
}
```

`$new_array` will have the right indexes.

Comment: And if you then copy it back to the original array, you'll be all set!

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr2 = array();
foreach($arr1 as $a) {
  $arr2[] = $a;
}
```

Put the values into a new, fresh array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a =  array(0 => 'tomato', 2 => 'apple', 3 => 'melon', 4 => 'Cherry', 7 => 'banana');
print_r($a);
$a = array_values($a);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just don't bother with re-indexing.
Use `foreach` to iterate it